# swift Task/Async not running in background and blocking main thread

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, async-await

I am trying to create a feed but using for now mocked data from JSON. However, it's extremely slow.

Below is my view for the feed

```
struct FeedView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
    @State private var isFeedSelected: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    if(isFeedSelected) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.feed) { post in
                            PostItemView(item: post)
                        }
                    } else {
                        ForEach(viewModel.classFeed) { classItem in
                            Text(classItem.userName)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding([.top], 10)
            .task {
                if(isFeedSelected) {
                    await viewModel.getFeed()
                } else {
                    await viewModel.getClasses()
                }
            }
```

The ViewModel is as below:

```
final class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var feedUseCase: FeedUseCase

    @Published var feed: [FeedItemEntity] = []
    @Published var classFeed: [ClassItemEntity] = []
    
    @Published var state: FeedState = .na
    
    @Published var hasError: Bool = false

    init() {
        self.feedUseCase = FeedUseCase.shared
        setupErrorSubscription()
    }
    
    func getFeed() async {
        Task.detached {
            let result = await self.feedUseCase.getFeed()
            switch(result) {
            case .success(let feed):
                self.feed = feed
            case .failure(let error):
                self.feed = []
                self.hasError = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getClasses() async {
        Task.detached {
            let result = await self.feedUseCase.getClasses()
            switch(result) {
            case .success(let classes):
                self.classFeed = classes
            case .failure(let error):
                self.classFeed = []
                self.hasError = true
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

the usecase is doing this:

```
enum UseCaseError: Error{
    case networkError, decodingError
}

final class FeedUseCase {
    
    static let shared = FeedUseCase()
    
    let repository: FeedRepositoryProtocol
    
    init() {
        self.repository = FeedRepository.shared
    }
    
    func getFeed() async -> Result<[FeedItemEntity], UseCaseError> {
        do {
            let feed = try await repository.getFeed()
            return .success(feed)
        } catch (let error) {
            switch(error){
                case APIServiceError.decodingError:
                    return .failure(.decodingError)
                default:
                    return .failure(.networkError)
                }
            
        }
        
    }
```

At the end the repo is simply doing this:

```
func getFeed() async throws -> [FeedItemEntity] {
        return try await service.getFeed()
    }
```

and then service as below:

```
func getFeed() async throws -> [FeedItemEntity] {
        guard let url = Bundle(for: MockedFeedService.self).url(forResource: "basic-test-feed-response",withExtension: "json"),
              let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            throw APIServiceError.badUrl
        }
            
        guard let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([FeedItemEntity].self, from: data) else {
            throw APIServiceError.decodingError
        }
        
        return result
    }
```

From what I notice, the `ForEach` loop seems constantly be called, and I think it may impact the performances. The app is very, very slow.

I am used to developing on Android and the coroutine mechanism is usually running on background, but it seems that on iOS, those calls are more complicated, or I am just missing something.

Any idea how to make the app efficient and smooth?

Thanks

Comment: There's a lot of code you posted, but what catches my eye is how you use `@MainActor` inside some `Task`s. You're aware that `@MainActor` exists for ensuring the code runs on the main (a.k.a. UI) thread, right?

Comment: You don't need to mark a function as async if its content is wrapped in `Task`, see the function `getFeed()` in `FeedViewModel `. In addition, the contents of `onAppear` will execute on the main thread when using `Task {}`, use `Task.detached {}` instead.

Comment: @lazarevzubov I wasn't aware. I am just starting on swift so I am collecting info from various source

Comment: Alternatively, instead of `.onAppear{...}`, you could try :
          `.task {
                    if(isFeedSelected) { await viewModel.getFeed() } else {  await viewModel.getClasses() } }` and removing the  `Task { @MainActor in ` from `getFeed()` and `getClasses()`. Also use `@StateObject private var viewModel = FeedViewModel()`

Comment: @lazarevzubov I updated the code in my description but the issue is still there

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I updated my code, it still very slow. just navigating in the app take a lot of times. clicking on other icon, take 30sec to react..

Comment: On the other hand, when you need code to run on the main thread, you need `MainActor`. E.g., I can see you call `hasError = true` from inside `Task.detached`. What you want to do is to do the work on background, inside `Task.detached`, and then notify the main thread on its results, e.g., `MainActor.run { hasError = true }`.

Comment: @lazarevzubov if I do that, xcode complain that the expression is async and not marked await.  I think I may have a more core issue in the way I approach it. Maybe a example of View -> ViewModel -> Repo using backrground call may help.

Comment: What about completely removing the use of async await if you are unsure how to use it properly. Will you still have the same performance issues, will they get better/worse? Maybe it will be easier to understand what is going on with your app if you make it simpler without the concurrency.

Comment: (Answering the question directed to me.) The pattern is this: `Task { await doBackgroundStuff(); await MainActor.run { notifyMainThread() } }`. No `async` is needed.

Comment: Are your `FeedItemEntity` and `ClassItemEntity` structs or other ObservableObject classes?
 How many of those do you have in your json file?
 Note, in `FeedView` the `isFeedSelected = true` and is never changed, is this really the code you are using?
You could try commenting the `setupErrorSubscription()` to see if there is something wrong there. Note `NavigationView` is deprecated, use `NavigationStack`.

Comment: Don't use `MainActor.run` use SwiftUI's natural flow and wait to go to the Main Actor when the call is complete and the UI is updating. Also get rid of those `Task.detached` the `async` on the `func` becomes irrelevant. `.task` automatically cancels any running task, you can use `task(id:selectedTab)`

Comment: @Seb – The only blocking code you’ve shared is your API service `getFeed`, which calls both `Data(contentsOf:)` and `decode(_:from:)`, which are synchronous functions. Make sure that those are not on the main actor. Frankly, it shouldn’t be on any actor, so it is probably best to mark it `nonisolated`, which, due to [SE0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md) would get it off any actor. But you should remove the unnecessary unstructured concurrency (`Task {…}` and `Task.detached {…}`). Stick with structured concurrency.

Comment: If you’re still having problems, I’d suggest sharing a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), where we can reproduce your problem. We can’t get very specific without being able to reproduce your problem. At this point, we can only guess at what the problem would be. All we can say at this point is that if main thread is blocked, it means that you’re doing something slow and synchronous on the main actor/thread somewhere…

Answer (score -3):

Since you are using async/await one way to speed it up is to remove the old Combine `ObservableObject`, e.g.

```
struct FeedView: View {
    @Environment(\.feedController) var controller // renamed from feedUseCase
    @State private var feed: [FeedItem] = []

    var body: some View {
        ...
        .task { // normally there is an id param for the feed you want to fetch
           do {
               feed = await controller.getFeed()
           catch {
               // it's good practice to set an error message in a state and show it
           }
        }
        ...
```

If you make your controller not main actor it will be even faster on a background thread. The reason for using an `EnvironmentKey` for your controller is so you can switch it for a mock when previewing.

Comment: My question is not strictly criticizing your answer, I'm just curious, what made you call Combine and its property wrappers legacy?

Comment: Changed to old, no updates in 4 years.